# External image not displaying in UITableViewCellStyle with MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am working through the touch (iOS) BestSellers sample project for MVVMCross.

When listing all books of a certain category an image is shown for each book. I am currently running this against the **iPhone Emulator** as I have keychain issues with my actual devices.

The image is not being displayed. Is this an emulator issue?

I cannot seem much on line about UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitles ImageUrl property. Is it as binding the  url as a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have paid closer attention to the Output Window.

I recreated the BestSellers sample from scratch as there were issues with Missing methods and Nuget packages.

My Setup.cs in the iOS project was not calling EnsureLoaded on the DownloadCache PluginLoader. I discovered this the long way by going through the MVVMCross code in Github (MvxBaseImageViewLoader)